# Redirection of C++ console output to C# console doesn't print anything

Tags: c#, c++, redirect

I want to get output of C++ console (printf("") statements) redirected to C# console.

Following is what I have got

```
        Process e = new Process();
        e.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        e.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        e.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\Projects\\ot\\x64\\Debug\\ot.exe";
        e.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        e.Start();
        e.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

But I'm not getting any output. C++ console doesn't print anything (which means output has been redirected) with these lines of codes neither C#.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: There is a big yellow note on [OutputDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) that says "The application that is processing the asynchronous output should call the WaitForExit() method to ensure that the output buffer has been flushed."

Comment: Thank you for the respond Raymond. But it's the same with WaitForExit() too. Actually my C++ is an application which use OpenCV.

When i use OpenCV related functions only the printf statements are not redirecting to C# console. Like if I use, 
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
after a printf statement that won't get redirected to C# console.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
    Process e = new Process();
    e.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    e.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    e.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    e.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\Projects\\ot\\x64\\Debug\\ot.exe";
    e.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    e.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    e.Start();
    e.BeginOutputReadLine();
    e.BeginErrorReadLine();
    e.WaitForExit();
    e.CancelErrorRead();
    e.CancelOutputRead();
```

I've put together a base class that can be used to wrap the [process class](https://www.windegger.wtf/2016/02/capture-command-line-output-in-c/) and help interacting with other processes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that answers should be self-contained; while links may be used to provide resources and additional information, the actual solution should be contained in the answer itself. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for guidance on answering questions on this site.